# Python methods that add numbers given in parenthesis

Tags: python, python-2.7

function should be like add(5)(10)(20) and answer should be 35

i.e. one should be able to supply arbitrary number of parenthesis. in python

Like it should work for any number of parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do what you are asking for:

```
class AddableInt(int):
    def __call__(self, n):
        return AddableInt(self + n)

def add(n):
    return AddableInt(n)

add(5)(10)(20) # evaluates to 35
```

This works because the call to `add(5)` creates an `AddableInt` with a value of 5.  No `__init__` method was declared in `AddableInt`, so it just uses `int`'s default constructor.  The subsequent calls `(10)(20)` each call `AddableInt`'s `__call__` method, which adds the argument to itself and creates a new `AddableInt`.

**Old answer:**

Python does not support what you are asking for.  The closest I can come up with is:

```
from functools import partial
def add(n=None, terms=None):
    if n is None:
        return sum(terms) if terms else 0
    else:
        if terms:
            terms.append(n)
        else:
            terms = [n]
        return partial(add, terms=terms)
```

Call it like:

```
add(5)(10)(20)() # Note the extra parenthesis on the end
```

Better would be to use:

```
sum((5,10,20))
```

Comment: It is working fine. But is it possible to skip that extra parenthesis on the end?

Comment: @WasifAle:  No.  The only way to make this work is to have each call to the function return a callable function except when some sentinel is reached.  I made the sentinel an empty call.  Serious question though, why in the world do you want this?  It is very unpythonic. I can't think of any situation where this would be an advantageous way of calling a function.  Why would you prefer this over other ways of calling a function?

Comment: Thank You Steven, actually it is a question given to me as an assignment. Even I don't know why it is given to me while this thing can be done more easily. Anyways thank you for your help.

Comment: @WasifAle:  See edit.  I managed to do what you are asking for.  Still, this construct is very unpythonic and I would never do this in code I was sharing with others.

Comment: Thank You Steven. Now this is exactly what I was asked for.

Answer (score -2):

In python you can define a function with arbitrary parameters like this:

```
def add(*args):
    total=0
    for num  in args:
        total+=num
        #or whatever you want to do with the numbers
    return total
```

The `*` tells the code that any and all parameters from here to the end are optional and there could be more than one. It stores all the extra parameters in a tuple. So if you called `add(5, 10, 20)` it will return 35 and it would store the numbrs like this:

```
args=(5, 10, 20)
```

This is a tuple. It will store multiple value values inside one value. so the parameter args would be equal to the whole tuple.

[This link](http://pythoncentral.io/fun-with-python-function-parameters/) might help you a little more.

Comment: Why the downvote? This would return the correct answer and it lets you call the function with an unknown number of parameters. If I made a mistake, please edit the post.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer doesn't address what OP is asking. You're using function parameters, while OP is asking about some sort of function currying. question clearly states: _one should be able to supply arbitrary **number of parenthesis**_